# Which is better? Java Development or Webworks?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

I'm new to Blackberry application development and I need a piece of advise. I want to start developing Blackberry applications. I'm having a hard time making a choice whether I should use Java Development or Webworks.

According to what I learnt about webworks, it loads a lot when navigating from one screen to another as compared to the generic java applications. I also learnt that for some reasons, your blackberry webworks application might not just work on some blackberry models, despite the models meeting the requirements to run a webworks application.

I will very much appreciate if I can get an advise which is better and the best approach to start (books I can get to get me started).

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: As BBDev already mentioned, look at the Developer Resource Center. Just a note that, RIM does not plan to support Java Development Tools for future devices. With new BB London device (BBX) the new development tools will be used (C++). And old apps written on Java won't be compatible with BBX devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop in both HTML5/Javascript and Java. Both have its pro's and cons.

HTML5/Javascript:
1. I find the layout of the UI to be easier and more flexible.
2. UI is developed once and applied to multiple devices (smartphones and playbook)

JAVA
1. Better logic
2. Better support available when needed
3. Better IDE (eclipse) will speed up development.

I have however decided to do all new projects in webworks as this is the future for all blackberry apps

Comment: How do you then handle resource loading in webworks. because it seems to load a lot. Every time you navigate to another page, it loads all the resources all over again. What's the way out?

Answer (score 0):

You cant say which is better it is depending on your requirement. So you choose your SDK which suits more to your requirements. And for starting see this link.
[Developer Resource Center](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/tkb-p/browser_dev@tkb).